# Name for variations of elements from several sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Consider the set $S=\{1,2,3\}$. As is well known,

$(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,3), \ldots, (3,3)$

are the *variations with repetition* of elements of $S$ taken two at a time. We can similarly define *variations without repetition*, *combinations*, and *permutations*.

Now consider we have *several* sets (two in this example): $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and $T = \{a,b\}$. You could build variations taking one element from each set:

$(1,a), (1,b), (2,a), (2,b), (3,a), (3,b)$.

My question: is there a *combinatorics* name for the set of these tuples? By "combinatorics name" I mean something similar to "variations", "combinations" etc, but for the multiple-set case.

Of course you could say this is just the Cartesian product $S \times T$; but I'm looking for a combinatorics name, if it exists. After all, from a combinatorics standpoint you don't usually say "Cartesian product $S \times S$"; you say "variations with repetition of elements of $S$ taken two at a time". What is the analogous for several sets?